# What's the most appropriate directory where to place files shared between users?

Tags: directory-structure, fhs

Or: **where can I put files belonging to a group?**

Suppose there are two users on a Unix system: *joe* and *sarah*. They are both members of the *movies-enthusiast* group. Where should I put their movie files?

- `/home/{joe,sarah}/movies` are not appropriate because those directories belongs to *joe* / *sarah*, not to their group;
- `/home/movies-enthusiast` is not appropriate too, because *movies-enthusiast* is a group, not a user;
- `/var/movies-enthusiast` might be an option, but I'm not sure this is allowed by the FHS;
- `/srv/movies-enthusiast` might be an option too, however movies are not files required by system services.

Comment: Voted up for mention of FHS!  This *nix user and casual sys admin of 20 years had not known of it. Thank you!

Comment: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Don't use**

- `/usr` is for sharable read-only data. Data here should only change for administrative reasons (e.g. the installation of new packages.)
- `/opt` is generally for programs that are self-contained or need to be isolated from the rest of the system for some reason (low and medium interaction honeypot programs, for example).
- `/var` is for *"files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system---such as logs, spool files, and temporary e-mail files."* I like to think of it like this: if your data wouldn't look right summarized in a list, it generally doesn't belong in `/var` (though, there are exceptions to this.)

**Use**

- `/home` is for user home directories. Some see this directory as being an area for group files as well. The FHS actually notes that, *"on large systems (especially when the /home directories are shared amongst many hosts using NFS) it is useful to subdivide user home directories. Subdivision may be accomplished by using subdirectories such as /home/staff, /home/guests, /home/students, etc."*
- `/srv` is an acceptable and often-preferred location for group files. I generally use this directory for group-shared files for the reason mentioned in Chris Down's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70701/26112); I see group file sharing as being a service that the server provides.

See the hier(7) man page (`man hier`) for more information of the purpose of each directory described by the FHS.

Comment: I suppose that in some more generic case one may use `/srv/data` directory for data files.

Comment: /srv : Data for services provided by this system https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM

Comment: Do you mean that they could create `/home/movies-enthusiast` and put anything inside that folder even though there isn't an user named `movies-enthusiast` ?

Comment: The answer is correct but I have a doubt - What should be the directory to be shared for user/groups but for software oriented for development? i.e: Java, Maven, Gradle

Answer (score 40):

In my opinion, the right place is `/srv/movies-enthusiast`. A "service" does not have to be a daemon or program, it just has to be a service that the system provides (such as being able to get your movies there). Here's a quote from the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM):

> /srv contains site-specific data which is served by this system.

I definitely think your usage falls under that definition, and provides a service.

Comment: I suppose that in some more generic case one may use `/srv/data` directory for data files.

Comment: That _"service"_ term makes confuse the purpose of `/srv` for the context of sharing data ... - for new readers consider read now from [3.17. /srv : Data for services provided by this system](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s17.html)

Answer (score 17):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (FHS) specifies a layout for "Unix distribution developers, package developers, and system implementors" to adhere to in order not to make a mess of **your** namespace.

As it is **your** namespace, you should choose any name you feel is suitable. If you find `/groups/movies-enthusiast` makes sense, you should put it there. If you like short path names because they are easier to type, `/g/movies-enthusiast` (or perhaps `/g/m-e`) would be suitable.

Because the paths you choose are not defined in the FHS, the distribution or third-party packages must not touch them. As such, you should read the FHS to know what paths may be used by compliant software (the table of contents will tell you most of what you need to know).

For example, I personally use `/av` for where I store my audio-visual content, `/src` for source code and `/data` for undefined data (such as virtual machine images, cd images, chroots, saved packages, etc).

Comment: I personally use /data for all such files, then /data/movies for audio-visual content, /data/src for source code, /data/music . all in one (hierarchical) place.

Comment: Following or adhering to standards of very often a good idea, even if you are not a dev, distro dev, pkg dev, or system implementor.

Comment: Adding a new directory _is not against_ the FHS; actually, I would argue that *not creating new directories is sometime required to remain FHS compliant*! The FHS specifically mention that any question that do not need to be coordinated between multiple parties is outside the scope of that standard. Therefore, trying to fit every eventual need inside one of the FHS-defined directories is bound to create situations where files are put inside directories where they should not be.

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing wrong with creating a new mount point or directory for this purpose from the root.

Particularly if this is the primary purpose of this system, I would just create

/movies-enthusiast

If there are other similar "groups", I may or may not prefer to host them together, eg

```
/data/movies-entusiast
/data/next-group
etc
```

or

```
/share/movies-enthusiast
/share/next-idea
etc
```

Questions to consider: Are you going to dedicate a mount-point for this purpose?

Have you considered softlinks?

In any case there are no rules.  If you want to make one user the custodian and give the rest access to this project space, feel free to host it in the user's home directory.  Or create a /home/shared/* name-space.  You are your own boss.

Oh, one thing:  Whatever you do, do document it.  It needs to become part of system recovery, daily checks, backups, etc.  Important configuration detains need to be noted (eg group memberships, permission sets, fs tunables for performance, and anything else that is not a default)

Answer (score 7):

It is important to remember that the FHS *addresses issues where file placements need to be coordinated between multiple parties such as local sites, distributions, applications, documentation, etc*; the FHS doesn't try to set rules for every single situation you may have: *local placement of local files is a local issue* ([FHS 3.0, section 1.1](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#purpose)).

Therefore, you may technically put your `movies` directory anywhere, *as long as it doesn't go against FHS conventions*. Still, your question was about the *most appropriate* place, so let's consider a few common answers (ordered from by most preferred to my less preferred, given your specific use case):

- `/<someprefix>/<groupname>` or `/media/<volumename>/<groupname>`: I honestly don't know why this option has a bad reputation in the Linux world, but let's make this clear: this is really *your* system, and the FHS says that you are free from creating new directories at the root level as long as you do not conflict with anything for which there is well-established semantics. You could for example create a directory `/groups` or `/shared` and organize files in these as you see fit. I know that some administrators prefer to have these somewhat isolated from the rest of the filesystem, so they mount a distinct volume (ie. under `/media/<volumename>/<groupname>`). Both are fine and both are FHS complient, really.
- `/srv/<groupname>` or `/srv/<someprefix>/<groupname>`: According to the FHS, *`/srv` contains site-specific data which is served by this system*. The FHS then goes on explaining that *the methodology used to name subdirectories of /srv is unspecified*. From my personal experience, most administrators that exploit the `/srv` directory goes on with a per-client, per-site or per-project subdirectory, and then put data directories at that level. However you structure it, the `/srv` is perfectly acceptable to store files to be shared among several users if you can reasonably consider that sharing these files constitute a service by itself. Ask yourself: "Would it make sense to eventually share those files through SMB/NFS/AFS/GIT/...?" If so, then you can reasonably consider that your directory is a local file sharing service, and thus store these inside a subdirectory of `/srv`, even though there is not a daemon actually serving those files to other systems.
- `/home/<groupname>` or `/home/<some-prefix>/<groupname>`: The FHS says: *`/home` is a fairly standard concept, but it is clearly a site-specific filesystem*. There is absolutely no requirement that every directory under `/home` be the name of an actual user, and it is acceptable to have subdirectories for groups, though precaution is required to avoid eventual conflicts between a group and a user. Still, I have seen this strategy in used in several large setups (notably universities) with some compartimentation strategy to avoid the possibility of conflict; for example, real users would have their home directories in `/home/students/<studentid>`, `/home/teachers/<username>` or `/home/staff/<username>`, while shared stuff would for example be put in `/home/workgroup/<workgroupname>`. Sometime they would also be a department subdivision; still, you get the idea. To be honest, I personally don't like this strategy, but it makes things a little bit easier when `/home` is distributed among several servers (for example via NFS), which is why it tends to be preferred in very large organizations.

Answer (score 1):

FHS is also to make admin easy so I would go with /srv for that reason though its not what I have done. Have perfect hindsight though. I use /export/srv because its on NAS.

If its a drop box then make sure that it is both setgid and sticky. Also ensure that those using it have a useful umask. However, don't use wheel as I have done in the example of file access modes. Don't strip eXecute or you will be in for a O_o surprise.

```
bash-3.2$ mkdir movies
bash-3.2$ sudo chmod 03771 movies
Password:
bash-3.2$ ls -ld movies/
drwxrws--t 2 andrewb wheel 68 Apr  4 17:09 movies/
bash-3.2$ umask 026
bash-3.2$ touch movies/junk
bash-3.2$ ls -l movies/
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 andrewb wheel 0 Apr  4 17:09 junk
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally opt for /usr/share/movies-enthusiast or /opt/movies-enthusiast

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a separate directory like /opt/movies , set appropriate user and group permissions for them and also you can use disk `quota` to avoid total disk consume..

Answer (score 0):

This is as much a comment as an answer (so please don't downvote me for it!), but it's way too long to fit in a comment.

I do two things, both of which avoid the issue you're facing.

1) I make a separate partition of all the free space on my system disk and label it dataspace. That's where all my current media files and other data go. It gets automounted as /media/dataspace and I put anything that's "data" under a directory called "data" to separate it from things like work files, vms, or iso images that I don't want to routinely backup.

Using a separate partition has the added benefit that, if it fills up, it doesn't compromise my system like it would if it were stored under / or /home.

2) I put most of my data/media, especially things I'm not using "right now", on another physical drive (USB in my case with a notebook). That makes it easy to backup and easy to attach to another computer, should the need arise.