# How to allow users share file access?

Tags: permissions, users, shared-folders

I'm managing a Ubuntu server with hundreds of users.

One user may want to share his files/folders to his significant other. A few users may be in the movies enthusiast club, while some of them are toastmaster members, to name but a few.

The relationships of the users are too complicated and the relationships or groups may be temporary.

If I understand correctly, `addgroup`, `usermod`, and sort of commands require `sudo` permission. If users have to ask me to create and add them to groups, I will be overwhelmed by these emails.

How would I allow users to share file access with less `sudo` involvement?

Unlike [What's the most appropriate directory where to place files shared between users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/whats-the-most-appropriate-directory-where-to-place-files-shared-between-users), I'm totally fine with users putting shared files in their own home folder.

Comment: You could write scripts for adding and removing users from groups then give delegates in charge of maintaining each group access to the scripts. You would need to be wary of the security risks this adds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software#Web-based_software

Managing groups, users, files might quickly become a chore, not to mention that it has its security risks and other complications.