# What's the most appropriate directory where to place development software shared between users?

Tags: directory, users, directory-structure, fhs, non-root-user

About share data (files and directories) among users within the same machine, has sense use the `/srv` directory it according with:

- [What's the most appropriate directory where to place files shared between users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/whats-the-most-appropriate-directory-where-to-place-files-shared-between-users)

I am assuming it is still valid or recommendable - correct me if that changed

But - What should be the directory to be shared for user/groups but for *software oriented for development*? i.e: Java, Maven, Gradle (all available from a `.tar.gz` file). It because has no sense have repeated the same unpacked directory for each user.

Comment: Why would the development tools not be installed as software is ordinarily installed on the system? I.e. via a package tool like `yum` or `apt`, or if locally compiled, installed under `/usr/local` (or your system's best equivalent)...

Comment: If I work with CI (`Jenkins`) I would installed many JDK versions, 11,15 and 17 - same for Gradle and Maven - it to test a project through many environments. You are right of course - for the repositories I use that approach for DB for example - mysql or postgresql - according with some tutorials, is not recommendable compile/install - is better use the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of programs:

1. Linux like. Their files are spread over all filesystem in accordance to files type/usage.
   No issues with that kind of programs. They are managed well by package managers.
2. Windows like. Every program file in one program-specific folder. Like `C:/Program files/XXX`
   Not good way. But if you have one or few such programs in Linux **place it in /opt**

Or you can create a directory in */home* for such purposes. */home/opt* for example. That case might be useful if you afraid of conflicts between your software and software that automatically chooses */opt*.

A software that to be used by only one person might be installed into *${HOME}/bin* But it is not your case.

Comment: If I work with CI (Jenkins) I would installed many JDK versions, 11,15 and 17 - same for Gradle and Maven - it to test a project through many environments. The mentioned software(s) are installed simply by unpackaging and updating either the `.bash_profile` or `.profile` files with the respective settings for them

Comment: @ManuelJordan It depends on a Java package type. 1 st or 2nd, described above. 
In the 1st case you can specify different root folders to install(i.e. to change / path for that installation). And that folders could be in /opt/java/
In the 2nd case, just unpack it into /opt/java/  subfolder. 
Also, there must be a guide to manage with multiple JDK's for Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, I know how configure `Jenkins` for multiple JDK/Maven/Gradle - but remember pls the goal is install all the developers tools in one shared folder (but where?) for multiple developers in the same PC, consider 2 brothers and 1 cousin - all studying in the same university and the same career - not sure that common is use `/opt` specially because the content is managed by the `root` - it requires root privileges create something there

Comment: @ManuelJordan   /opt/devtools/... and so on. I hope it won't cause any trouble with other software. Just install everything there and share it.
Another possible case /home/devtools

Comment: I am sure the software installed by hand and configured/defined on `.profile` does not exist installed through the _repositories_ - I am going to use `/opt/somename` - not sure why use `/home/devtools` - other user would assume `devtools` is an user, and that's not correct